# Double integral; changing order of integration

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

I'm attempting some exercises on double integration in Schaum's Outline of Calculus. The integral is

$$I = \int_{y=1}^{2}\int_{x=0}^{y^{3/2}} \frac{x}{y^2}\ dx\ dy.$$

I can do it in this direction and it turns out to be $I = \frac{3}{4}$ but for some reason I'm struggling to swap the order of integration and I think I may be confused.

I presume it'll be in the form of

$$I = \int_{x = \text{const}}^\text{const}\int_{y = \text{const}}^{y(x)} \frac{x}{y^2}\ dy \ dx$$

Comment: See if you can draw out the region that you are integrating over. With that done, it's not too hard to restate the bounds with the variables switched.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Originally, you have $y$ as independent variable such that $y \in (1,2)$ and $x$ as dependent variable such that $x \in (0,y^{3/2})$, or thus $0 < x < y^{3/2}$.

If you now want $x$ to be the indepent variable, note that the maximal value of $y^{3/2}$ is $2^{3/2}$. So $x \in (0,2^{3/2})$. Then, since $x < y^{3/2}$ or thus $x^{2/3} < y$. Thus $y \in (x^{2/3},2)$. But, at the same time, $y \in (1,2)$ so $y \in (\max\{1,x^{2/3}\},2)$.

Comment: Should the result necessarily be the same in either "direction"?

Comment: Since $\frac{x}{y^2}$ is bounded on the area of integration, and you are integrating over a bounded area: YES. 

If your function becomes infinite on the area of integration, or you are integration over an infinite area, things may get tricky. You should read up on [Fubini's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fubini%27s_theorem) if you're dealing with such situations.

Answer (score 2):

After drawing the region I think the Integral will be broken in 2 parts. The limit of 1st part should be $y=1$ to $y=2$ and $x=0$ to $x=y^{1.5}$ . The limit of second part should be $y=x^{\frac{2}{3}}$ to $y=2$ and $x=1$ to $x=2^{1.5}$.

Comment: The first part is just the integral that I did in the "direction" $dxdy$?

Comment: @Jahambo99  For the 1st part x=y^(1.5) is equal to 1

Answer (score 0):

$$\begin{align}\int_{1}^{2}\int_{0}^{y^{3\over2}}{x\over y^2}dxdy \\\end{align}$$

$$\begin{align}=\int_{0}^{1}\int_{y=1}^{y=2}{x\over y^2}dydx+\int_{1}^{2\sqrt{2}}\int_{y=x^{2\over3}}^{y=2}{x\over y^2}dydx\end{align}$$

$\space$$\space$$\space$$\space$$\space$$\space$$\space$$\space$$\space$$\space$$\space$$\space$$\space$$\space$$\space$$\space$$\space$$\space$$\space$$\space$$\space$$\space$$\space$$\space$$\space$$\space$[image]

I hope it can help you.